# I am using auth0 for user authentication, and I have a API for CRUD posts (title, img, desc). How to make authenticated calls to the CRUD api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, authentication, express

i'm building a react app, and to login/authenticate users I am using auth0.

Before I had used auth0, I had been making CRUD calls to my API to make posts.  This is again, before using auth0 and before I had users, so I was just making posts willy nilly.

Now that I am using auth0, I have it set up so it inserts the user I made into a `Users` collection in my mongodb.  So, each user now has an `id` which I am going to use to associate to posts.

After logging in, auth0 sends a token (which I store in localstorage) which looks like this: `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGviOdJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovLzI4MTMzMC5hdXRoMC5jb20vIiwic3ViIjoiYXV0aDB8NTc4M2VjMjlkYmIxMAEwMTAwNTE1M2VmIiwiYXVkIeoiTzE3MGJkNnlnc3lCODkyY295Y25haVhyVkpQZHBUUlgiLCJleHAiOjE0Njw0NjkyMDQsImlhdCI6MTQ4ODDzMzIwNH0.gte9fxVURQGzOWD1ZF8AB-JachZuIkYmux6WKOZ-fdk`

Here's my question - how do I make authenticated calls to my CRUD api?  That is, only logged in users can make API calls.  I have not had much success finding tutorials around this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to do is set the auth token as a header in every request from your client.  Since you say that auth0 is sending a token for a logged in user, you can simply store this token (probably hashed for security, etc., but this question isn't about security) in your database, in your user's object.

Once you've set the token in the header, you can grab it in the `request` object in express, and search for it in your database.  If it's valid, then you've successfully authenticated the request (and know what which user made it).  If the request doesn't have a valid auth token in the header, you can send back a `403` error.

Probably the easiest way to do this is in a middleware, where you can simply set a value on all requests that come in tracking whether they are authenticated or not.

For example, in express:

```js
function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
  //grab your auth token
  var authToken = req.get('X-Authentication-Token'); //or whatever you've set the name of your auth header to be in the client
  
  //decrypt it it you have to, etc.
  
  //pseudo code.  You'd have, for example, a function that would 
  //search for the auth token in your database, and return the user 
  //object if it exists, and throw an error if it didn't.
  validateTokenFromDB(authToken).then(function(user) {
    //you can set some values on your request here, so that they're 
    //available later to your handlers.
    req.user = user;
    req.authToken = authToken;
    next();
   }).catch(function(err) {
     //return your 403.
     return invalidRequest(req, res);
   });
}

function invalidRequest(req, res) {
  res.status(403);
  res.end('{"error":"unauthorized"}');
}
```

You can now just apply this middleware to whatever routes you want to protect.

Again, of course I'm not dealing with token hashing and not sending and sending tokens with plain text, TLS, etc., in my example. Just illustrating the general architecture of using auth tokens.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend sending th token in you Authorization header in format Bearer: . Instead of storing the tokens, you can verify the signature of the tokens using your client secret-- this can be done using [any of the SDKs for JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/). You can learn more [in the Auth0 quickstarts for React](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react) and the [Auth0 server tutorials](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend) for your chosen technology.

Hope this helps!